# Apply a smarty modifier to JS?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

quick question I have some JS and want to apply a smarty modifier to a var in JS.

In smarty I have a modifier called cash which converts a value in currency format

eg.

> $price = "1";
>
> {$price|cash}

would output £1.00

Please can anyone advise how I can apply this modifier to js below:

> var price

also I would like to specifically use smarty as I have other modifiers that I would like to apply to js. (just incase someone was going to tell me to create a javascript function)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is there anything else we can help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot operate on JavaScript variables to get their value. Smarty can operate only on its variables - they either come from PHP or are set in Smarty. JavaScript variable cannot be set anyway to Smarty so you cannot do it.

But in case you want to assign PHP/Smarty variable with modifier to JavaScript it should be possible:

In PHP:

```
$price = '1';
$smarty->assign('price', $price);
```

Smarty modifier:

```
function smarty_modifier_cash($value)
{
    return '&pound; '.number_format($value,2);
}
```

Smarty template file:

```
{$price|cash}


<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    var cash = {/literal}'{$price|cash}'{literal};
    alert (cash);
{/literal}
</script>
```

As a result you have displayed:

```
£ 1.00
```

on your site and get JavaScript alert with:

```
&pound; 1.00
```